# connectionDidFinishLoading called multiple times .. why?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I'm using
    `NSURLConnection *theConnection=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];`

and I notice while debugging code that

```
connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
```

called multiple times, any clue why?

Comment: Could you please post some more code so we can find a potential solution.

Comment: Are you sure you aren't starting multiple connections?

Comment: While you debug it, try to NSLog the connection object or write down its address to some piece of paper. I guess that you will find out that those objects have different addresses. If so then the connection parameter refers to different connection objects. That would mean that you have invoked the connection a number of times (for whatever reason - a bit more of your code might give the answer)

Comment: I agree, it sounds like you might be sending multiple requests. Maybe you're sending the request as a response to some user event? (mapview changes, user touches?)

Comment: Or do you send the request in some loop or in some method that is called frequently? Such as cellForRowAtIndexPath of a UITableViewController?

Comment: Yes, you are right, there was some mistake in my code, which I figured out after readings your comments, it works fine now ... Many Thanks!!!